# NHibernate inconsistent data between different sessions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent NHibernate and Sqlite to build a winform system. There are many threads runing when system start up. so I use per session per thread strategy to solve session concurrency problem. Then I find there are inconsistent data between different sessions. so, I start using second level cache to share data in different sessions. But, I still find that I update objects by one session, then I get the updated objects by another session, I see the returned objects are stale. **I guess that the second level cache do not notify the first level cache when data updated. How to solve it?**

Configuration:

1. Second level cache provider: NHibernate.Caches.SysCache
2. Fluent mapping: Cache.ReadWrite(); in classmap

Comment: Showing a little of your data access code may help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using each session as a unit of work.  When you're done, dispose of it and get a new one of the next session you need.

Comment: But, in winform app, it is very hard to find the suitable session dispose opportunity.

I think we can config that notify every session cache when second level cache updated . Do you know how to config it?

Comment: Not hard at all.  Usually your users request data.  You don't need the session once you've retreived it.  Then your app has it and they may work with it for a while.  If they save, that's another UoW.  Again, dispose when you're done.

Comment: Besides you will love to use NHibernate that way, it's not how it work (and if you really think about it, it won't make sense anymore). Avoid headaches, use one single session per event you are handling and never share the objects between unit of works (sessions). Keep it simple and straight.

Answer (score 0):

The only way your changes actually make it to the database is through a session flush.

There are 3 events that cause a session to flush:
1. You tell it to by calling session.flush();
2. The session is being closed
3. A select statement is about to execute

If you haven't triggered a flush, your data isn't in the database yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have flush the session when commit transaction. I am sure that the first session have update the data to database. The problem is that the other session get the updated objects not from the second level cache but from the session cache which are stale data.  I guess that the second level cache do not notify the first level cache when data updated. 

Any more ideals? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you sure? Have you checked the DB for the correct value at the appropriate time? (i.e. adding a break-point before you select the data in your 2nd session and actually looking at the data in the DB?

Comment: Yes, I checked the DB. I think I should find the method to config the session cache refresh strategy. But, I don't know how to config it.